# QT: Which slot to use for Window show

Tags: qt

I have two windows. Upon a button click of window form A, I need to open window form B and load some data through an http request in B's table widget.
I want to know which slot do I need to implement to get it done?

Answer (score 1):

```
connect(formA->button, SIGNAL(clicked()), formB, SLOT(showAndInitialize()));
```

For form B you need to implement your own slot `void showAndInitialize()` where you can call `this->show()` and initiate the http request.